# How to setup Magento 1.9 with Docker and Docker Compose

Tags: apache, docker, magento, docker-compose, magento-1.9

I am trying to run my Magento 1.9 application on Docker using Docker Compose.

I have managed to successfully set everything up. The MySQL database is running and can be accessed from my Magento container. The problem is that Magento is throwing a 500 error, but not giving me any additional context to what the problem might be, so I have no idea where to start.

Apache is using its default configuration. I don't have a .htaccess file in the directory. I don't see any errors in the containers STDOUT and nothing is being written to `var/log/system.log`.

Does anybody have any suggestions about what I might be doing wrong?

This is my docker-compose.xml file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: 'magento'
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - db
    volumes:
        - /Users/marchorne/projects/magento:/var/www/html/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    environment:
        - MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE=true
  db:
    container_name: 'mysql'
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
        - MYSQL_USER=root
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
        - 3308:3306
    volumes:
        - /Users/marchorne/projects/magento/dumps:/dumps/
```

and this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

COPY .:/var/www/html/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

RUN apt-get install curl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash

RUN apt-get install nodejs yarn -y

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: You are copying data to `/var/www/html/` in your Dockerfile and mounting a folder to it in compose file. Is this intended?

Comment: Yeah, I was under the impression that the volume needs to be specified in order for the local and docker files to be synced, but also the volume doesn't affect the building of the image

Comment: No, it will bypass the content of the image and only show the files from your host. Does the error occure during building or when you run the container?

Comment: When I run Magento in the container. Everything else seems good. I can connect to the mysql db from the container, apache is throwing no errors. The problem is Magento doesn't throw any errors either, just shows me 500 page, nothing in the logs

Comment: Rename file errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml file  then you will  get what error  throws magento

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Apparently package installation was disabled/restricted.

Running `rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php` removed the restriction and allowed me to use `apt-get` normally.